# Send SMS to UK numbers from Website

Tags: php, mobile, sms-gateway

Is it possible to do this at all? I have read that its possible to do it to US numbers but I would like the opportunity to send people SMS updates if they have subscribed but just send them using PHP if possible

Comment: It's possible, there are any number of services to do this. It generally costs 5/10pence per message to send. (Unlike in some countries there are few free services because the sender pays the whole cost of the message unlike other places where the receiver might pay some or all of the cost)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need an [SMS gateway service](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=uk+sms+gateway+provider&oq=uk+sms+gateway+provider&sugexp=chrome,mod=8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that supports UK numbers.

I won't recommend a specific one, but Google will toss up lots.

Answer (score 0):

Check out cbfsms, I think they provide the service you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Use email2sms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways

Answer (score 0):

Find an SMS service provider. I used Esendex but there are many others

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can refer to [Nexmo](http://www.nexmo.com/) for help. It offers free APIs and pre-built libraries to integrate with your website/platform to send SMS at very low prices to over 200 countries.

Disclaimer: I'm a member of the Nexmo team.

Answer (score -1):

Contact with phone operators and ask them if it is possible and what you will need for that...

Comment: Unless you want to operate your own gateway service (which I doubt the OP wants), that way lies madness. Get a middleman.